# Help with arguing against symmetry proofs.

Tags: solution-verification, symmetry

I am asking for the help of mathematicians here to show my colleague that her arguments are wrong. I tried my best to explain that inequalities and equations can be solved like that, but maybe my arguments were not good enough.

Some of the examples of her solutions:

**Example 1.** Over the real numbers, if $x+y=2$, what is the maximum value of $xy$?

**Solution:** By symmetry, there must be a maximum or minimum when $x=y$ so $x=y=1$ and $xy=1$. This is clearly a maximum, since if say $x=0$ and $y=2$, you get a lower value.

**Example 2.** Let $x, y$ and $z$ be positive real numbers such that $x + y + z = 1$. Prove that $\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2} \geq 27$.

**Solution:** By symmetry, there is a minimum at x=y=z hance all = 1/3 and the expression equals 27.

**Example 3.** For positive numbers $a,b,c$ prove that $\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{c+a}} \leq \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}$?

**Solution:** Another of those symmetry arguments.  The LHS is a maximum for $a=b=c$ and then equals the RHS.

---

It is very clear, that these are not even close to be called solutions. When I (or my other collegaues) try to explain that it not that simple to show that extreme points will be at $x=y=z$ we get answers like

> It's a symmetry thing.  If you imagine that say $a$ tends to 0 or infinity you see that the LHS is going to decrease.

> have repeatedly said that symmetry arguments do not always work.  However, it must be obvious to any bright 18 year old that the argument does work in this particular case.

> Much to my amazement, many people in this group do not understand how to solve problems using symmetry. In England, this is taught in schools.

I am not sure what will help us to explain that it does not work like that. If we will get many reponces here, I believe it will help to convince my colleagues. Also, if you are from UK or have degree from prestigous college it will be helpfull to mention that.

Comment: It suffices to find a counterexample, doesn't it?

Comment: @Servaes that makes sense, but I think the goal is not to show that it is it wrong in general, since she says: "have repeatedly said that symmetry arguments do not always work". I think the goal is to show that it is not that easy as "use symmetry then everything solved"

Comment: Instead of arguing with your collegue, you might together investigate *under what conditions* the symmetry argument works or fails.

Comment: Some people use killer arguments like "it must be obvious to any bright 18 year old" or "in England, this is taught in schools" or even "as every pre-school child knows". Don't worry, the only intention is to make you feel like a fool because you are not able to understand such a "really obvious" thing. And if it should not work always, then at least in this particular case ... only you simpleton cannot to see that.

Comment: But taken seriously, the point is that symmetry arguments are in fact often useful, but you cannot a priori be sure that symmetric solutions are optimal in the given situation. If somebody can see that at first glance, he must have a lot of experience or says it ex post (after he has verified it the quite chamber).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that your colleague seems to be confusing a useful heuristic with a proof.   If the principle of why something 'must be true' by symmetry cannot be articulated and only applied ex post, then that's a red flag that it's not a proof.  One approach is to suppose your colleague is right in 2 simple separate cases, then combine them (via multiplication in this case) and show that the 'principle' breaks.

A better way to view 'symmetry arguments' when looking at inequalities involving symmetric functions like example 1, is through majorization.  The deeper reason example 1 holds is that $x_1\cdot x_2$ is symmetric and in fact a Schur concave function and the constraint $x_1+x_2=2$  ensures that $\mathbf x =\mathbf 1$ is majorized by any other candidate.  By Schur concavity this is a maximum.

Alternatively consider $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^2_{\geq 0}$ and $\mathbf x\mapsto x_1^4 + x_2^4$ with the constraint $x_1+x_2=2$.  This is symmetric and in fact a Schur convex function.  The candidate $\mathbf x =\mathbf 1$ is a minimum since it is majorized by all other allowed choices of $\mathbf x$ and Schur convexity ensures that is a minimum.

Finally consider consider $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^2_{\geq 0}$ and $\mathbf x\mapsto  (x_1\cdot x_2)\cdot(x_1^4 + x_2^4)$ with the constraint $x_1+x_2=2$.   This is a symmetric function but neither (Schur) concave nor convex. Being majorized by all choices of $\mathbf x$ (what your colleague calls the symmetric solution) doesn't tell you anything definitive.  Hence applying a heuristic like *"It's a symmetry thing. If you imagine that say  tends to 0 or infinity you see that the LHS is going to decrease"* misleads you despite the fact that this is a symmetric function.  And $\mathbf x =\mathbf 1$ is neither a maximum or a minimum, as $0$ is a clear minimum e.g. as $x_1\to 0$ but e.g. $x_1=1.5, x_2=0.5$ is much larger than the constant solution.

**conclusion:** your colleague's heuristic is true when dealing with symmetric functions that are Schur convex (concave). But not all functions are Shur convex (concave); understanding this is vital.  The theory of majorization is a well developed mathematical theory quite distinct from declaring things are obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Example 1 does not seem so bad at first sight. It is true that by symmetry (and smoothness of the functions) $x=y$ is a stationary point, hence it probably forms a *local* maximum or minimum.

Anyway, exhibiting a lower point is not enough to prove that we have a global maximum.

If we absorb the constraint with $x=1-t,y=1+t$, we only have to maximize $1-t^2$ and it turns out that the unique stationary point is a maximum, which favors your colleague.

Now, on the opposite, the function $t^2-t^4$, corresponding to the maximization of

$$(4xy+1)(x^2+y^2)-x^4-y^4-6x^2y^2-2xy$$ under $x+y=2$, induces an asymmetric solution.